# How to put notes on top of PDF sheet music document?

Tags: piano, sheet-music

I have a lot of sheet music in PDF files, and I'd like to write notes* on top of them arbitrarily without printing them out.

Such as placing numbers on top of musical-notes (for fingers) and just any other scribbles (just text is fine!). With ability to save those notes too!

Could convert all the pages individually to images and then work with photoshop, but there has to be a better way!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help, though I do not recognize the names of any of the apps. 
https://goingdigitalmusician.wordpress.com/page/2/

Comment: That's good, deals exactly with the topic at hand!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the full version of Adobe Acrobat (not just the reader) you can edit and annotate PDF documents. Other PDF utilities may do this at lower cost also.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase and probably find free programs which allow editing of PDF's.  If you don't want to purchase anything and can't find a freebie, there are several pdf2jpg websites that will convert your PDF's to JPG's then pull your JPG files into PAINT in MSWIN and use a music font to add notes or even text.  This is much easier than your Photoshop method.  Then, use a JPG2PDF website to convert it back.  That is the long way but it  works. Alternatively . . .

I have used free PDF editors in the past but don't remember what they were.  Now I convert everything to JPG because they are much easier to use and manipulate. There are a dozen music fonts out there for free.

Just do a Google search for "free PDF editor" and you'll find them or you'll see several websites that will do it for you.  I prefer websites because there is nothing to download or install.  So what if they are peeking up my skirt, I don't care.